# Navigate between modules in Python

Tags: python, menu, module

I'm trying to navigate between modules in Python but I can't return to main menu. 
This is the arch: `main.py` calls `opa.py` and `opb.py`

main.py:

```
import sys, opa, opb

def menu():
    print '1. Go opA'
    print '2. Go opB'
    print '3. Exit'
    pick    = raw_input('Pick one: ')

    if pick == '1':
        opa.menu()
    elif pick == '2':
        opb.menu()
    else:
        sys.exit()  
menu()
```

opa.py:

```
def menu():
    print '1. Speak'
    print '2. Return'
    pick    = raw_input('Pick one: ')
    if pick == '1':
        print 'OpA'
    elif pick == '2':
        main.menu()
```

opb.py:

```
def menu():
    print '1. Speak'
    print '2. Return'
    pick    = raw_input('Pick one: ')
    if pick == '1':
        print 'OpB'
    elif pick == '2':
        main.menu()
```

When I pick 2 in `opa.py` and `opb.py` the program breaks with this error [in this case I go onto opa.py and select "2. Return"]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    menu()
  File "main.py", line 10, in menu
    opa.menu()
  File "opa.py", line 8, in menu
    main.menu()
NameError: global name 'main' is not defined
```

If I add `from main import menu` I get this other one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sys, opa, opb
  File "opa.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import menu
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    menu()
  File "main.py", line 10, in menu
    opa.menu()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'menu'
```

And I get it before loading opa.py or opb.py

Any suggestions?

**SOLUTION**:
The arch was wrong, so I put the imports after the imports. Like that:

```
def menu():
    print '1. Go opA'
    print '2. Go opB'
    print '3. Exit'
    pick    = raw_input('Pick one: ')

    if pick == '1':
        import opa
        opa.menu()
    elif pick == '2':
        import opb
        opb.menu()
    else:
        import sys
        sys.exit()

menu()
```

Comment: Add `import main` in `opb.py` and `opa.py`

Comment: also please double check your indentation before submitting...I have corrected it

Comment: I've got new errors. I edited the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The program breaks" is a bit unclear, but most likely you forgot to add imports of your main menu():

Insert `import main` on top of your other files and it should do the trick.

Comment: You're right, I've already edited and I've added the errors. Also, I modified opa.py and opb.py adding the import and breaks in other way.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit in a hurry when I was answering: Just write `import main` in your `op[a,b].py` and it should work. I just tested it on my computer (all three files in the same folder, the only modification was to import main in opa and opb).

Comment: I get the same error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'menu'` What can be? :/

Comment: Two suggestions: a) delete all .pyc - files in your folder and try again. b) rename "main.py" to something else (e.g. main_menu.py) and don't forget to change your imports.

Comment: I did what you told and didn't work. Then I was thinking about the arch. I realise that I imported all files when I loaded some one, so I put the imports just below the if condition. I've edited the topic with the solution. Thanks a lot @obu